# Cannot run WireShark on Ubuntu 20.04 - This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized

Tags: 20.04, wireshark

I am trying to run WireShark on my Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS Server system and I am getting the below error. I have attempted a restart of the machine, reinstalling WireShark after purging all it's packages but it's sadly no use. Using the command `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` has showed me an extended trace of what could be the issue but unfortunately I am completely lost.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right place on getting WireShark working. It could be i've installed a package that's breaking it or a simple command I am missing. Apologises if it's really obvious, I cannot understand it whatsoever.

Thanks, Jasmine.

```
root@S01:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
root@S01:~#

root@S01:~# wireshark
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.395910 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms" ...
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.395981 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396044 [GUI WARNING] -- Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396075 [GUI ECHO] -- Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396085 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396128 [GUI WARNING] -- Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396152 [GUI ECHO] -- Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396162 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396195 [GUI WARNING] -- Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396215 [GUI ECHO] -- Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396227 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396260 [GUI WARNING] -- Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396283 [GUI ECHO] -- Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396294 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396327 [GUI WARNING] -- Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396354 [GUI ECHO] -- Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396363 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396398 [GUI WARNING] -- Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396421 [GUI ECHO] -- Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396433 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396462 [GUI WARNING] -- Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396480 [GUI ECHO] -- Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396490 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/bin/platforms" ...
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396527 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/bin/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396547 [GUI ECHO] -- Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396556 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/bin/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396572 [GUI ECHO] -- Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396582 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/bin/platforms/libqminimal.so"
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396600 [GUI ECHO] -- Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396609 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/bin/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396625 [GUI ECHO] -- Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396635 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/bin/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396653 [GUI ECHO] -- Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396663 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/bin/platforms/libqvnc.so"
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396677 [GUI ECHO] -- Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396686 [GUI ECHO] -- QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/bin/platforms/libqxcb.so"
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.396702 [GUI ECHO] -- Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.397942 [GUI ECHO] -- loaded library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.398001 [GUI WARNING] -- could not connect to display
 ** (wireshark:21258) 03:19:38.398042 [GUI ERROR] -- This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

 ** (wireshark:21258) Aborting on fatal log level exception
Aborted (core dumped)
root@S01:~#
```

Comment: There are instructions on installing Wireshark on 20.04 [here](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-and-use-wireshark-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/). Is this what you followed?

Comment: Have you tried not running Wireshark as root? Root may cause problems for the xcb (X11) platform plugin initialization. You can add yourself to the group it tells you to to gain permissions

Comment: @graham This was tried and sadly did not work. Sadly get the same issue after completely purging the entire wireshark entries and apt autoremove.

Comment: @DanielT Sadly this did not work. I have attempted a reinstall as stated above, then I got presented with the following again: https://jasmeow.pics/DFxuGA.png

Comment: @JasmeowTheCat Please reboot after adding groups instead of using `su`, to avoid missing environment variable problems. Then remove the `sudo` word in front of wireshark when you try to run it. If it still gives that error, do any other Qt application (such as any KDE app) do so as well?

Comment: Since this is a server system, are you connecting over SSH? Then you need to use the `-X` flag. Another strange thing is the impossible `/usr/bin/platforms` (only executables, not folders should be in bin). Did you set some environment variable in /etc or .bashrc/profile?